# Replace values in columns based on a column index in a R data set

Tags: r

I have a dataset with multiple columns - all filled with zeros - and one numeric index column. Now I would like to replace the zero within the column that match the column index (1 = first column, 2 = second column...)

Simplified example:

```
input <- tibble(X1 = c(0,0,0,0), X2 = c(0,0,0,0), X3 = c(0,0,0,0), index = c(1,2,2,3))
output <- tibble(X1 = c(1,0,0,0), X2 = c(0,1,1,0), X3 = c(0,0,0,1), index = c(1,2,2,3))
```

I already found one solution, but I'm curious if there is a better/easier way to write it (maybe with base R).

```
input %>% 
    select(index) %>% 
    bind_cols(map2_dfc(.x = c('X1', 'X2', 'X3'),
    .y = 1:3,
    .f = ~input %>%
    transmute(!!sym(.x) := if_else(.y == index, 1, 0))))`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `data.frames` and base R, you can do

```
input <- as.data.frame(input)
input[cbind(seq_along(input$index), input$index)] <- 1
input
```

Answer (score 3):

```
input[1:3] <- model.matrix(~factor(index)+0, input)

input
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     X1    X2    X3 index
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0     1
2     0     1     0     2
3     0     1     0     2
4     0     0     1     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with `map2_dfc`

```r
 input %>% mutate(map2_dfc(.x=across(starts_with('X')), 
.y=seq_along(1: (length(.)-1)), .f= ~ ifelse(index==.y, 1, 0)))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     X1    X2    X3 index
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0     1
2     0     1     0     2
3     0     1     0     2
4     0     0     1     3
```